# EMM Policy Proxy Setting for WIFI Networks

Tags: android, proxy, android-management-api

Hy!

I created a policy for our devices with wifi settings.
I am able to connet to the wifi but i don't internetaccess because of missing proxy settings. I have not found any information about proxy setup on google emm page.https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies
Does anybody know how to configure proxy via android device policy.

```
{
"name": "enterprises/myenterpriseid/policies/browserkiosk",
"version": "32",
"applications": [
 {
  "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
  "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
  "lockTaskAllowed": true,
  "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
  }
 }
],
"screenCaptureDisabled": true,
"openNetworkConfiguration": {
 "NetworkConfigurations": [
  {
   "GUID": "id2",
   "Name": "name2",
   "Type": "WiFi",
   "WiFi": {
    "AutoConnect": true,
    "SSID": "wlan2",
    "Security": "WPA-PSK",
    "Passphrase": "password2"
   }
  },
  {
   "GUID": "id1",
   "Name": "name1",
   "Type": "WiFi",
   "WiFi": {
    "AutoConnect": true,
    "SSID": "wlan1",
    "Security": "WPA-PSK",
    "Passphrase": "password1"
   }
  }
 ]
},
"systemUpdate": {
 "type": "WINDOWED",
 "startMinutes": 120,
 "endMinutes": 240
},
"factoryResetDisabled": true,
"safeBootDisabled": true,
"statusBarDisabled": true,
"keyguardDisabled": true,
"statusReportingSettings": {
 "softwareInfoEnabled": true,
 "memoryInfoEnabled": true,
 "networkInfoEnabled": true,
 "displayInfoEnabled": true,
 "powerManagementEventsEnabled": true,
 "hardwareStatusEnabled": true
},
"complianceRules": [
 {
  "nonComplianceDetailCondition": {
   "settingName": "persistentPreferredActivities"
  }
 }
],
"blockApplicationsEnabled": true,
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in chromium os doc.

But openNetworkConfiguration is not fully supported on android.

Proxy is working now, but you cannot see the configured proxy in wifi settings on device.

```
"openNetworkConfiguration": {
  "NetworkConfigurations": [
   {
    "GUID": "id1",
    "Name": "name1",
    "Type": "WiFi",
    "ProxySettings": {
     "Type": "Manual",
     "Manual": {
      "HTTPProxy": {
       "Host": "proxy.test.intra",
       "Port": 1234
      }

     }
    }
 "WiFi": {
    "AutoConnect": true,
    "SSID": "wlan1",
    "Security": "WPA-PSK",
    "Passphrase": "password1"
   }
```